# Einstein summation convention of 2-forms: $T_{ik}\omega_{kj}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, trace

I am familiar with Einstein summation convention that means

> if the same index name appears exactly twice, once as an
> upper index and once as a lower index, then that term is understood to be summed
> over all possible values of that index.

But what is the meaning of the following? Let $\omega=\omega_{ij}E^i\wedge E^j$ and $T$ a (symmetric) $2$-tensor
$$T_{ik}\omega_{kj}.$$
Which index should I raise then contract it? index of $T$ or of $\omega$? in the global notation, it is $\omega(T)$ or $T(\omega)$ with appropriate converted $(1,1)$-tensors?

Also I have another problem with Einstein summation convention for 2-forms $\omega=\omega_{ij}E^i\wedge E^j$, that is the sum cannot range over all possible values of its index because $\omega=\sum_{i<j}\omega_{ij}E^i\wedge E^j$ so $i$ cannot be $n$ for example, while in $T$ it can. Unless we see $\omega$ as 2-tensors as well then the notation $\omega=\omega_{ij}E^i\wedge E^j$ is meaningless and it should be $\omega=\omega_{ij}E^i\otimes E^j$ with $\omega_{ij}=-\omega_{ji}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that you are working in a Riemannian setting so you have a metric $g_{ij}$ and its inverse $g^{ij}$ around. Then the question "which index should I raise and the contract" does not really occur, since what you want to form is $g^{k\ell}T_{ik}\omega_{\ell j}$ and by symmetry of $g^{k\ell}$ there is no choice involved. The notations $\omega(T)$ and $T(\omega)$ tend to be ambiguous anyway, in the end, the index notation is more precise here.

The two interpretations of index notation for two-forms (i.e. via $\sum_{i<j}$ or via $\sum_{i,j}$ and $\omega_{ji}=-\omega_{ij}$) are indeed there and they both are meaningful. In an interpretation involving contractions you have to take the interpretation as a tensor field with skew symmetric coefficients. Observe that also the result of your operation is a tensor field and not a two-form. I think it is also good to keep in mind that there actually is a linear algebra meaning hidden behind the index expression. You have bilinear maps $T(x),\omega(x):T_xM\times T_xM\to\mathbb R$ for which in addition you know that $\omega(x)$ is skew symmetric. Your contraction then expresses the bilinear map $(X,Y)\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^nT(X,e_i)\omega(e_i,Y)$ where $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_xM$ (and the result is independen from which orthonormal basis you uses).

Comment: Thanks. By $\omega(T)$ it could be $\omega(T(-),-)$ or, $\omega(-,T(-))$ or $\omega(T(-),-)-\omega(-,T(-))$. for $T\circ \omega$ as well.

Comment: one can argue similarly that $T_{ijkl}S_{lstu}$ is also meaningful by symmetry of metric.  Yeah?

Comment: yes, this is true for any type of contractions

Comment: Am I right that, the first para is because of this: $T\times (g\times S) = (S^t\times (g\times T^t))^t $? I confused a little. Does $g\times T$ and $T\times g$ and $g\times T^t$ and $T^t\times g$ are different for metric tensor $g$ and arbitrary tensor $T$ seen as matrix? ($t$ is transpose operation.)

Comment: I am not sure how you want to interpret tensors in terms of matrices and also the meaning of transposition is subtle in this context, so I cannot really answer that. It is an issue of multilinear algebra, but I don't think that there is a good explanation without using tensor products or multilinear maps.

Comment: What is that interpretation problem? Tensors are generalization of matrices so rank 2 tensors (equivalently (0,2) or (1,1) or (2,0)-tensors ) are $n\times m$  matrices and rank 3 tensors are $n\times m \times k$ cubic matrices in my opinion. so transpose makes sense.

Comment: in your words, what is the meaning of this : "by symmetry of $g^{kl}$ there is no choice involved"

Comment: The interpretation problem is that you use matrices to describe bilinear forms and to describe linear maps without carefully distinguishing. In one case, there is an obvious meaning of transposition (you just swap the entries of a bilinear form), in the other case you need an inner product for transposition to make sense (it has no meaning for abstract vector spaces without inner product). And I wouldnn't know what you mean by transposition for cubic matrices, there are several ways to permute indices here.

Comment: The point about symmetry of $g^{ij}$ is that the only possible difference between the two possible ways to contract that you describe would amount to specifying into which index of $g$ each of the two tensors is contracted. This does not play a role by symmetry.